# Write log to command prompt/terminal from headless eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, plugins, headless

I am currently working on a headless eclipse application. What I want is to log errors and info from the command prompt instead of eclipse console but I can't seem to make it work. To make it more clear, what I do is open a command prompt terminal, and then execute a command line like

```
eclipse -nosplash -data <workspace> -application my.headless.plugin arg1 arg2
```

The plugin works fine except that I cannot see any logs in the command prompt. When debugging I can see the logs displayed in eclipse console but that is not what I ultimately want. I tried a simple system.out.println and also I tried log4j console appender but to no avail. I hope someone can help me figure this out.

Comment: System.out.println should work for a headless app. I have written many headless app that did just that.

Comment: Hi greg-449, thank you. It's exactly why I am confused because a simple syso code would have done the trick but unfortunately it does not on my case. So I have a plugin, then created an extension for a headless application. So my action class implements IApplication. In the start() method I did not put any logic but just a simple Sytem.out.println code. When I debug, the message is displayed in eclipse console. But when doing the installed testing, I open a command prompt to execute command, and the application is running for sure but no message displayed in my command prompt. :(

Comment: Btw I am using IBM RSA. I run my headless app this way: I open command prompt from IBM/SDP directory where the eclipse.exe is. Then I input command with this: eclipse -nosplash - data myworkspace -application my.headless.application then hit enter. I can see from task manager that eclipse is running so definitely my code is being executed and I expect a message to be written in command prompt but it is not. I also tried executing command via java -jar but still the same result. Is there a configuration I am missing? Or is this a limitation of RSA? I have not tried it yet in a pure eclipse IDE.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, when I run command in this way java -jar 

".\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.1.R36x_v20101122_1400.jar"

I can output standard out logs in command prompt. But when i run it using

eclipse - nosplash...

It does not output any logs in the terminal. But I need it to run this way and not using the java -jar. Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

Check your ini file about the vm args for JAVA path,

if you use -vm  ..../jre/bin/javac.exe , change it to -vm .../jre/java.exe